# Property of an irreducible Markov Chain

Tags: conditional-probability, markov-process

How can we prove that if a Markov Chain is irreducible (does not contain any closed set), then every state can be reached from every other state in the chain ?

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction: if there was a state, $i$, from which you could not reach some other state, $j$, $i$ would have to be in a closed set.

Comment: How could you prove that you can always construct a closed set containing state $i$ ? Let S be the set of reachable state from $i$, then could you say that the set $C = E_{i} \cup S$ is always closed?

Comment: I'm assuming $E_i$ is the set of edges out from $i$? Anyway let's say that $E_S$ are all the out-edges in the set, $S$, that $i$ belongs to. If this set were not closed, $E_S$ would contain some edge that connected $S$ to the rest of the Markov chain, in which case you could simply use this edge to leave $S$ and reach $j$.